# how to set $compile code in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I compile a string but it's not reflect on dom like.

I have some string like :

```
result = '<tr ng-click="someFun()" rowid="hh_'+gameId+'" id="hh_'+gameId+'" ng-class="game.currVideoReplay[' + gameId + '] ? \'active-current-hand\':\'\'">' + uCHtml + cCHtml + pTHtml + dCV +'</tr>';

result = $compile(result)($scope);

angular.element(document.querySelector("tbody")).html(result);
```

but it's show on DOM like :

`<tbody class="hh-list">[[object HTMLTableRowElement]]</tbody>`

question is how I show my actual data in DOM.

Comment: did you try this `$compile(result)($scope).html();`??

Comment: You should define your html in templates, and avoid building it up in code where you can

Comment: no @RameshRajendran it's not working and #devqon I can't do that because my string come from server

Comment: please show us what does console.log(result) returns before calling $compile

Comment: and try element.find('tbody').append(result); (you can inject element to your link function in your directive, or $element if it is a controller

Comment: I solved this question: need to include jquery plugin. thanks all

Answer (score -1):

## TL;DR

`$compile` returns an element, which must be appended to the DOM as is. You cannot just set the HTML.

e.g.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector("tbody")).append(result);
```

## How does Angular's compiler work?

When you compile markup with Angular's `$compile` service, it parses the HTML and turns it into a DOM fragment with a single top level element. Then it goes through all the elements and their attributes to see if there are any directives that need to be applied. Any directives will be compiled and linked for the relevant element object.

These directives may or may not store some data using jQuery or jQueryLite's `.data()` method on the elements. They may also add some event handlers, or other things.

If you then try to just get the HTML of that DOM fragment, *all of that jQuery data and event handlers and other JS functionality will be lost*. HTML by itself is inert, it doesn't do anything. Only when JS functionality is attached will it do what you expected.

So stop thinking of Angular as producing HTML. What it really produces is a DOM tree imbued with data and JS functionality that can only be represented with element objects, not just HTML.